# Div Image & Text Alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a banner that runs across the bottom of the front page of a site that I'm designing. The banner is divided into 4 equal sections. Each section (div) is comprised of two more sections (divs). One of the two sections is an image, while the other section is text. I would like for all of the image containing divs to align horizontally with their respective text divs. Here is a link to an example.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22196024/Banner-Test/banner-test.html

Thanks in advance for the help!

P.S. Also, why are the Furniture and Equipment boxes different in width than the Supplies and Printing boxes? Thanks!

[Update] I also apologize, because as you can probably tell I'm much more of a designer that a developer.

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly your question is. Also, furniture and equipment are different because the images are different size and therefore take up a different amount of space.

Comment: For example I want the stapler to be centered horizontally with the div containing both the title and the description.

Comment: Do you mean centered *vertically*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not that correct.

Instead of

```
<div class="one_fourth first">
        <div class="iconbox">
            <span class="iconbox_icon">
                <img src="furniture-icon.png" alt="">
            </span>
            <div class="iconbox_content">
                <h3 class="iconbox_content_title">Furniture</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

you might do:

```
<div class="box box1">
     <h3>My h3 title</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

and style it with css, setting a background image for each box.

Comment: They are restricted to that format, because it is a plugin for WordPress that generates it that way. I'm just trying to style it a certain way.

Comment: You can position the images absolutely inside a relatively positioned parent (`div.iconbox`) to make them behave like background images.